# Is it possible to add multiple UIGravityBehaviors to a UIDynamicAnimator?

Tags: ios, uikit, uikit-dynamics

I'm trying to create a view where some items fall along normal gravity vector and others fall along an opposite vector

```
self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self];

// Normal Gravity
self.gravityBehavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[ ]];
self.gravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0, 1);
[self.animator addBehavior:self.gravityBehavior];

// Inverse Gravity
self.inverseGravityBehavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[ ]];
self.inverseGravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0, -1);
[self.animator addBehavior:self.inverseGravityBehavior];
```

I would think then I could just add some items to one behavior and some to the other, but it appears that adding the second gravity behavior overrides the first?

```
    [self.gravityBehavior        addItem: ballA];
    [self.inverseGravityBehavior addItem: ballB];
```

**Is this true, and if so is there another way to achieve this effect?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is definitely possible. However, it cannot be achieved with one animator using differing `UIGravityBehavior`s.

One solution would be to use two `UIDynamicAnimator` instances, each with its own `UIGravityBehavior` instance. Below is an example of a view controller that has two tap gesture recognizers attached, one for single tap, and one for double. The single will add a view that reacts to normal gravity. The double tap adds a view that reacts to inverted gravity. Obviously the code would need to be tweaked to match your specific requirements.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDynamicAnimator *secondAnimator;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIGravityBehavior *normalGravity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIGravityBehavior *inverseGravity;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

    self.normalGravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] init];
    [self.animator addBehavior:self.normalGravity];

    self.secondAnimator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
    self.inverseGravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] init];
    [self.inverseGravity setAngle:self.normalGravity.angle magnitude:(-1.0 * self.normalGravity.magnitude)];
    [self.secondAnimator addBehavior:self.inverseGravity];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)viewWasTapped:(id)sender {
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 10, 25, 25)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:v];
    [self.normalGravity addItem:v];
}

- (IBAction)viewWasDoubleTapped:(id)sender {
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 400, 25, 25)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:v];
    [self.inverseGravity addItem:v];
}

@end
```

---

A second option would be to use a `UIPushBehavior` to simulate inverted gravity. Below is a similarly set up view controller, but without the second animator and using the push behavior.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIGravityBehavior *normalGravity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPushBehavior *pushBehavior;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

    self.normalGravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] init];
    [self.animator addBehavior:self.normalGravity];

    self.pushBehavior = [[UIPushBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[] mode:UIPushBehaviorModeContinuous];
    [self.pushBehavior setAngle:self.normalGravity.angle magnitude:(-1.0 * self.normalGravity.magnitude)];
    [self.animator addBehavior:self.pushBehavior];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)viewWasTapped:(id)sender {
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 10, 25, 25)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:v];
    [self.normalGravity addItem:v];
}

- (IBAction)viewWasDoubleTapped:(id)sender {
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 400, 25, 25)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:v];

    [self.pushBehavior addItem:v];
}

@end
```

---

In all situations be sure you are managing which items are being impacted by the `UIDynamicAnimator` and the various behaviors so that you are not constantly adding to them and bogging the simulation down.

Comment: This is a great answer. Unfortunately I wasn't explicitly clear in my question: what I really wanted was one  `UIDynamicsAnimator` for animating collisions of all items, with half the items being pulled in opposite directions.

I think this could be solved adequately with the later solution though? Even if it is not ideal I think this answers the question.

Comment: I've been meaning to test this and comment back but have not found the time—so sorry for the delay!

Comment: @Warpling yes, the second option should handle collisions correctly. It is effectively just applying an force opposite to the direction of gravity and using the same animator.

Comment: Would you say that the `UIGravityBehavior` is a specific `UIPushBehavior`?

Comment: Conceptually, yes. But I do not know if that is how it is implemented. The inheritance tree for `UIGravityBehavior` does not include `UIPushBehavior`.